# Can I set AccessFileName for a serverAlias?

Tags: apache, virtualhost

There is a way, on Apache (2.4), to set a different AccessFileName for each serverAlias inside the virtualHost?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is *not* possible.

The documentation clearly states that the `AccessFileName` directive can be used in server and in virtual host context:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#accessfilename

However the `ServerAlias` directive does not create a separate configuration entity, but just a name alias, just as it's name suggests. That means different aliases cannot have different configurations.

---

What you *can* do however is this:

You define two separate virtual hosts with different values for the `AccessFileName` directive. The rest of the configuration can be identical. In fact you can even place it in a separate file and include that shared configuration in *both* virtual hosts.

That should give you *exactly* what you are looking for.